# RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property "Text"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I am trying to set/get the text of my RichTextBox, but Text is not among list of its properties when I want to get test.Text...

I am using code behind in C# (.net framework 3.5 SP1)

```
RichTextBox test = new RichTextBox();
```

cannot have `test.Text(?)`

Do you know how come it can be possible ?

Answer (score 139):

to **set** RichTextBox text:

```
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Text")));
```

to **get** RichTextBox text:

```
string richText = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

Comment: Contructor 'Run' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s) , same for Paragraph

Comment: @alvinmeimoun Actually, `Paragraph()` had a `Paragraph(Inline)` overload [at least since .NET 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597388(v=vs.90).aspx) (and `Run(string)` was also valid - it's even in the example).

Comment: why so complicated?

Comment: How to add `FontFamily` in paragraph  ?

Answer (score 67):

There was a confusion between RichTextBox in [System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) and in [System.Windows.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)

I am using the one in the Control as I am using WPF. In there, there is no Text property, and in order to get a text, I should have used this line:

```
string myText = new TextRange(transcriberArea.Document.ContentStart, transcriberArea.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

thanks

Answer (score 39):

The WPF RichTextBox has a `Document` property for setting the content *a la* MSDN:

```
// Create a FlowDocument to contain content for the RichTextBox.
        FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

        // Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument.
        myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 1")));
        myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 2")));
        myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 3")));
        RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();

        // Add initial content to the RichTextBox.
        myRichTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;
```

You can just use the `AppendText` method though if that's all you're after.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 18):

Using two extension methods, this becomes very easy:

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static void SetText(this RichTextBox richTextBox, string text)
    {
        richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(text)));
    }

    public static string GetText(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        return new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
            richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

There is no `Text` property in the WPF RichTextBox control. Here is one way to get all of the text out:

```
TextRange range = new TextRange(myRTB.Document.ContentStart, myRTB.Document.ContentEnd);

string allText = range.Text;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
string GetString(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    var textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
RichTextBox rtf = new RichTextBox();
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(yourText));

rtf.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

OR

```
rtf.Selection.Text = yourText;
```

Answer (score 8):

How about just doing the following:

```
_richTextBox.SelectAll();
string myText = _richTextBox.Selection.Text;
```

Comment: Best answer that i could find so far :) Here my code if you want to paste the Length in another Textbox in a GUI:    `rtxb_input.SelectAll();`
            `txb_InputLength.Text = rtxb_input.Selection.Text.Length.ToString();`

Answer (score 4):

"Extended WPF Toolkit" now provides a richtextbox with the Text property.

You can get or set the text in different formats (XAML, RTF and plaintext).

Here is the link: [Extended WPF Toolkit RichTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox&referringTitle=Home#properties)

Answer (score 0):

To my big surprise the `RichtTextBox` does not return the same value as was set !

Setting a string With:

```
SelectAll()
RichTextBox.Selection.Text = "AA"
```

And returning with:

```
SelectAll()
Return RichTextBox.Selection.Text
```

Returns "AA" with carriage-return

Also using:

```
Dim Selection = New TextRange(rtbRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, rtbRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd)
Selection.Text = "AA"
```

And returning with:

```
Dim Selection = New TextRange(rtbRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, rtbRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd)
Return Selection.Text
```

Does the same: "AA" with `carriage-return`

The `RichTextBox` does not return the value as set
Very incorrect behaviour !!

Is solved (circumvented) this by:

```
Dim Selection = New TextRange(rtbRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, rtbRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-1))
Return Selection.Text
```

Answer (score -12):

According to this it does have a Text property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_members.aspx

You can also try the "Lines" property if you want the text broken up as lines.

Comment: This is WPF, not Win Forms.