# Rich Text box Properties problem

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

```
<RichTextBox AcceptsTab="True" ForceCursor="True" IsDocumentEnabled="True" TextChanged="ContentChanged" Name="TextContent"/>
```

In C# file i am not able to get Text property of Rich Textbox. 
I am trying to get this like;

```
TextContent.Text= "hello"
```

But it is giving compile time error.

```
'System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: You need to use the Document property, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text

Comment: are you actually trying to read or write content? Because you asking how to get and trying to set in example... Anyway, i have added examples in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you need to work with [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.blocks%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property. But, if you are using [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) for representing `RichTextBox` content, then you can access text with [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) property.

For example, writing content:

**XAML:**

```
<RichTextBox Name="rtb">
</RichTextBox>
```

**Code:**

```
FlowDocument contentForStoring =
    new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Hello, Stack Overflow!")));
rtb.Document = contentForStoring;
```

To read content you simply access `Document` property:

```
FlowDocument yourStoredContent = rtb.Document;
```

If you need just to take text, you have more simple way - [`TextRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.aspx) class. Next code will retrieve all text content:

```
TextRange storedTextContent =
    new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
string yourText = storedTextContent.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the text from the rich text box then use this code,

```
string content = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```