# C# String in RichTextBox Wpf

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have the following question:

I have a class Question which has a property BodyString of the type String.
How do I put this String in a Wpf-RichTextBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
yourRichTextBox.AppendText(BodyString);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text):

The WPF RichTextBox has a Document property for setting the content a la MSDN:

```
// Create a FlowDocument to contain content for the RichTextBox.
FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

// Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument.
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 1")));
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 2")));
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 3")));
RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();

// Add initial content to the RichTextBox.
myRichTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;
```

You can just use the AppendText method though if that's all you're after.

Hope that helps.