# How to retrieve RichText content From (MySQL) table to a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid, rtf

I have an application where I have to store (and retrieve) supplier data from and into my WPF page, one of the fields is a RichTextBox

On my Xaml page I defined the Rich text block like this

```
<TabItem Header="Memo">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
       <TextBlock   Text="Comments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Margin="10,10" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkRed"/>
       <RichTextBox x:Name="inpSupplierMemo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,70,10,0" Height="182" Width="Auto">
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text=""/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

In my MySql Database table I defined the field as LONGTEXT

[image]

My C# Code to store the rich text data into the field:

```
private void ToolbarButtonSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string ContentSupplierMemo;

    if (inpSupplierCode.Text != "")
    {
        TextRange tr = new(inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentStart, 
        inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentEnd);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new())
        {
            tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
            ContentSupplierMemo = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    else { ContentSupplierMemo = ""; }

    Database dbConnection = new Database
    {
        TableName = DatabaseTable
    };

    dbConnection.Connect();
    dbConnection.SqlCommand = "UPDATE ";
    dbConnection.SqlCommandString = " SET " +
    "supplier_Code = '" + inpSupplierCode.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_Name = '" + inpSupplierName.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_Address1 = '" + inpSupplierAddress1.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_Address2 = '" + inpSupplierAddress2.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_Zip = '" + inpSupplierZip.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_City = '" + inpSupplierCity.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_Url = '" + inpSupplierUrl.Text + "', " +
    "supplier_Memo = '" + ContentSupplierMemo + "', " +
    "supplier_Id = " + valueSupplierId.Text + ";";

    dbConnection.TableName = DatabaseTable;

    _ = dbConnection.UpdateMySqlDataRecord();
    DataTable dtSupplierCodes = dbConnection.LoadMySqlData();

    // Load the data from the database into the datagrid
    SupplierCode_DataGrid.DataContext = dtSupplierCodes;

    // Make sure the eddited row in the datagrid is selected
    SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(valueSupplierId.Text) - 1;
    SupplierCode_DataGrid.Focus();
}
```

For so far Showing the RichTextBox and saving the data.
If I run the application I am able to enter text and save it (Save button not shown in the screenshot)

[image]

The content of the richtext box is stored in the database

[image]

And content in detail

[image]

**So far so good**
But when I retrieve the content from the database I am not able to show the original content anymore.

My C# code for data retrieval:

```
private void SupplierCode_DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

    if (dataGrid.SelectedItem is not DataRowView Row_Selected)
    {
        return;
    }

    valueSupplierId.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Id"].ToString();
    inpSupplierCode.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Code"].ToString();
    inpSupplierName.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Name"].ToString();
    inpSupplierAddress1.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Address1"].ToString();
    inpSupplierAddress2.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Address2"].ToString();
    inpSupplierZip.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Zip"].ToString();
    inpSupplierCity.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_City"].ToString();
    inpSupplierUrl.Text = Row_Selected["supplier_Url"].ToString();
    inpSupplierMemo.Document.Blocks.Clear();

    // Read formatted ritch text from table and store in field
    string ContentSupplierMemo = Row_Selected["supplier_Memo"].ToString();

    if (ContentSupplierMemo != "")
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ContentSupplierMemo);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new(byteArray))
        {
            TextRange tr = new(inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentStart, inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentEnd);
            tr.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result of this code is:

[image]

But I expected

[image]

Where do I go wrong, can someone help me with this.

I googled for three days now and only see more or less the same solution, tried different ones, but with this solution I come closest to my goal, but not there yet.

Regards,
Herbert

Comment: Make sure to use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Can you check the value for "valueSupplierId" if it is actually the n'th row in your datagrid (no gaps, no reordering, ...)

Comment: @user9938, i want to parametertize later when the code runs ok, still in a learning proces so taking small steps

Comment: I've added two posts below-one uses `longtext` and the other `longbinary`.  Since, there are a number of differences between the two-in order to avoid confusion-I added the complete code in each post. In the `longtext` version, you'll notice that I've used `UTF8` instead of `ASCII` when converting the string to byte[]. The two methods to focus on are  `GetMemo()` and `GetRichTextFromFlowDocument()` in "MainWindow.xaml.cs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a demo project that shows how to store data from a TextBlock in a database. It also shows how to retrieve the data from the database and display it in a TextBlock.

The following code has been tested. `longtext` is used for `supplier_Memo`. Alternatively, one could use `longblob` (or `mediumblob`, if it meets your needs). Since `longblob` is binary data, the code below would need to be modified to pass data as `byte[]` instead of `string`.

It's also important to use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

---

Create a new `WPF App (.NET Framework)` project (name: DatabaseMySqlHN)

**VS 2019**:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DatabaseMySqlHN.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatabaseMySqlHN"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnCreateTbl" Click="btnCreateTbl_Click">Create Table</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnInsertTestData" Click="btnInsertTestData_Click">Insert Test Data</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="4" x:Name="btnGetData" Click="btnGetData_Click">Get Data</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="6" x:Name="btnSaveUpdate" Click="btnSaveUpdate_Click">Save/Update</Button>
        </Grid>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="SupplierCode_DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="SupplierCode_DataGrid_SelectionChanged"></DataGrid>

        <TabControl Grid.Row="4" x:Name="tabControl1">
            <TabItem Header="Memo">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock   Text="Comments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Margin="10,10" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkRed"/>
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="inpSupplierMemo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,70,10,0" Height="182" Width="Auto">
                        <FlowDocument Name="inpSupplierMemoFD">
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text=""/>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Name="textBoxStatus" IsReadOnly="True" Text="" Background="LightGray"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Database table**: Supplier

**Note**: In the code below, I've tried to maintain the database column names that were supplied in the OP. However, the table name really shouldn't be part of the column names.

Instead of naming the column `supplier_Code`, name the column `Code`.

Columns may need to be added/modified per your requirements.

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier (supplier_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                                           supplier_Code varchar(4),
                                                           supplier_Name varchar(80),    
                                                           supplier_Address1 varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Address2 varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Zip varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_City varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Url varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_MailSales varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_MailSupport varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Memo longtext,
                                                           currency_Id int,
                                                           currency_Code varchar(4));
```

[image]

Create a class (name: HelperMySql.cs)

**HelperMySql.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DatabaseMySqlHN
{
    public class HelperMySQL
    {
        public string ConnectionStr { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public HelperMySQL(string serverName, string databaseName, string username, string userPwd)
        {
            ConnectionStr = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Uid={2};Pwd={3};", serverName, databaseName, username, userPwd);
        }

        public HelperMySQL(string serverName, int portNumber, string databaseName, string username, string userPwd)
        {
            ConnectionStr = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Database={2};Uid={3};Pwd={4};", serverName, portNumber, databaseName, username, userPwd);
        }

        public string CreateTableSupplier()
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                //for mySQL, use backticks if tablename has space in it
                //total max size for all columns is 65535 - excluding TEXT and BLOB
                string sqlText = @"CREATE TABLE Supplier (supplier_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                                           supplier_Code varchar(4),
                                                           supplier_Name varchar(80),    
                                                           supplier_Address1 varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Address2 varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Zip varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_City varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Url varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_MailSales varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_MailSupport varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Memo longtext,
                                                           currency_Id int,
                                                           currency_Code varchar(4));";

                ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText);

                Debug.WriteLine("Info: Table created (Supplier)");
                msg = "Status: Table created (Supplier).";
                
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                msg = "Error: (CreateTableSupplier - MySqlException) - " + ex.Message;
                Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                //throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error: (CreateTableSupplier) - " + ex.Message;
                Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                //throw ex;
            }

            return msg;
        }

        public void ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlText)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
            {
                //open
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
                {
                    //execute
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        public int ExecuteNonQueryTblSupplier(string sqlText, string supplierCode, string supplierName, string supplierAddress1, string supplierAddress2, string supplierZip, string supplierCity, string supplierUrl, string supplierMemo, int supplierId = 0)
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
            {
                //open
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
                {

                    //set values - if they exist
                    //if a value is null, one must use DBNull.Value
                    //if the value is DBNull.Value, and the table column doesn't allow nulls, this will cause an error

                    //add parameters setting string values to DBNull.Value
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = supplierId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierAddress1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierAddress2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierZip", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierCity", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierUrl", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierMemo", MySqlDbType.LongText).Value = DBNull.Value;

                    //set values
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierCode))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierCode"].Value = supplierCode;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierName))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierName"].Value = supplierName;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierAddress1))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierAddress1"].Value = supplierAddress1;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierAddress2))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierAddress2"].Value = supplierAddress2;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierZip))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierZip"].Value = supplierZip;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierCity))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierCity"].Value = supplierCity;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierUrl))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierUrl"].Value = supplierUrl;

                    if (supplierMemo != null && supplierMemo.Length > 0)
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierMemo"].Value = supplierMemo;

                    //execute; returns the number of rows affected
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            return rowsAffected;
        }

        public DataTable GetDataTblSupplier(int supplierId = 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string sqlText = string.Empty;

            if (supplierId > 0)
            {
                sqlText = "SELECT * from Supplier where supplier_Id = @supplierId";
            }
            else
            {
                sqlText = "SELECT * from Supplier";
            }

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
            {
                //open
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
                {
                    //add parameter
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = supplierId;

                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        //use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }

        public string InsertTblSupplier(string supplierCode, string supplierName, string supplierAddress1, string supplierAddress2, string supplierZip, string supplierCity, string supplierUrl, string supplierMemo)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Supplier  (supplier_Code, supplier_Name, supplier_Address1, supplier_Address2, supplier_Zip, supplier_City, supplier_Url, supplier_Memo) VALUES (@supplierCode, @supplierName, @supplierAddress1, @supplierAddress2, @supplierZip, @supplierCity, @supplierUrl, @supplierMemo);";

            try
            {
                int rowsAffected = ExecuteNonQueryTblSupplier(sqlText, supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplierZip, supplierCity, supplierUrl, supplierMemo);

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {

                    result = String.Format("Row added.");
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "Row not added.";
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier - MySqlException): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public string UpdateTblSupplier(int supplierId, string supplierCode, string supplierName, string supplierAddress1, string supplierAddress2, string supplierZip, string supplierCity, string supplierUrl, string supplierMemo)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            string sqlText = "UPDATE Supplier SET supplier_Code = @supplierCode, supplier_name = @supplierName, supplier_Address1 = @supplierAddress1, supplier_Address2 = @supplierAddress2, supplier_Zip = @supplierZip, supplier_City = @supplierCity, supplier_Url = @supplierUrl, supplier_Memo = @supplierMemo WHERE supplier_Id = @supplierId;";

            try
            {
                int rowsAffected = ExecuteNonQueryTblSupplier(sqlText, supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplierZip, supplierCity, supplierUrl, supplierMemo, supplierId);

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    result = "Updated successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "No rows were updated.";
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier - MySqlException): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace DatabaseMySqlHN
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private HelperMySQL _helper = null;
        private System.Data.DataTable _dt = null;
        private int _currentDataGridIndex = 0;
        private int _dbRowCount = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            InitializeHelper();

            //get data from database
            _dt = _helper.GetDataTblSupplier();

            //populate data in DataGrid from DataTable
            SupplierCode_DataGrid.DataContext = _dt;

            //set value
            _dbRowCount = _dt.Rows.Count;

            //clear existing data
            inpSupplierMemo.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        }

        private void GetMemo(int index)
        {
            string ContentSupplierMemo = string.Empty;

            if (_dt != null && index >= 0 && index < _dt.Rows.Count)
            {
                //set value
                DataRow row = _dt.Rows[index];


                if (row["supplier_Memo"] != null && row["supplier_Memo"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    //get value from DataTable
                    ContentSupplierMemo = row["supplier_Memo"].ToString();
                }
            
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentSupplierMemo))
                {
                    //Debug.WriteLine("Length: " + ContentSupplierMemo.Length);

                    //clear existing data
                    inpSupplierMemo.Document.Blocks.Clear();

                    //convert to byte[]
                    byte[] dataArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ContentSupplierMemo);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataArr))
                    {
                        //inpSupplierMemo.Document = new FlowDocument();

                        //load data
                        TextRange flowDocRange = new TextRange(inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentStart, inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentEnd);
                        flowDocRange.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetRichTextFromFlowDocument(FlowDocument fDoc)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            //convert to string
            if (fDoc != null)
            {
                TextRange tr = new TextRange(fDoc.ContentStart, fDoc.ContentEnd);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void InitializeHelper()
        {
            if (_helper == null)
            {
                //servername, databaseName, userName, userPassword
                _helper = new HelperMySQL("localhost", "HN", "testUser", "removed");
            }
        }

        private void InsertRow(int dgIndex)
        {
            //since the DataGrid DataContext is set to the DataTable, 
            //the DataTable is updated when data is modified in the DataGrid
            //get last row
            DataRow row = _dt.Rows[_dt.Rows.Count - 1];

            //get data from DataTable
            string supplierCode = row["supplier_Code"].ToString();
            string supplierName = row["supplier_Name"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress1 = row["supplier_Address1"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress2 = row["supplier_Address2"].ToString();
            string supplier_Zip = row["supplier_Zip"].ToString();
            string supplier_City = row["supplier_City"].ToString();
            string supplier_Url = row["supplier_Url"].ToString();

            //convert RTF to string
            string memo = GetRichTextFromFlowDocument(inpSupplierMemo.Document);

            InitializeHelper();

            string result = string.Empty;
            result = _helper.InsertTblSupplier(supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplier_Zip, supplier_City, supplier_Url, memo);
            UpdateStatus(result);
        }

        private void UpdateRow(int dgIndex)
        {
            //when DataGrid SelectionChanged occurs, the value of '_currentDataGridIndex' is set
            //to DataGrid SelectedIndex
            //get data from DataTable
            DataRow row = _dt.Rows[_currentDataGridIndex];

            int supplierId = (int)row["supplier_Id"];
            string supplierCode = row["supplier_Code"].ToString();
            string supplierName = row["supplier_Name"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress1 = row["supplier_Address1"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress2 = row["supplier_Address2"].ToString();
            string supplier_Zip = row["supplier_Zip"].ToString();
            string supplier_City = row["supplier_City"].ToString();
            string supplier_Url = row["supplier_Url"].ToString();

            //convert RTF to string
            string memo = GetRichTextFromFlowDocument(inpSupplierMemo.Document);

            InitializeHelper();

            string result = string.Empty;
            result = _helper.UpdateTblSupplier(supplierId, supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplier_Zip, supplier_City, supplier_Url, memo);
            UpdateStatus(result);
        }

        private void UpdateStatus(string msg)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
            {
                if (!msg.StartsWith("Error") && !msg.StartsWith("Status"))
                {
                    textBoxStatus.Text = String.Format("Status: {0} ({1})", msg, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Status: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), msg));
                }
                else
                {
                    textBoxStatus.Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", msg, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), msg));
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnCreateTbl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeHelper();

            //create table
            string result = _helper.CreateTableSupplier();
            UpdateStatus(result);
        }

        private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetData();

            //update status
            string msg = "Status: '" + _dt.Rows.Count + "' rows retrieved.";
            UpdateStatus(msg);
        }

        private void SupplierCode_DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;

            //set value
            _currentDataGridIndex = dg.SelectedIndex;

            GetMemo(dg.SelectedIndex);
        }


        private void btnSaveUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = _currentDataGridIndex;

            if (_dt.Rows.Count >  _dbRowCount)
            {
                InsertRow(SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateRow(SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            }

            GetData();

            // Make sure the eddited row in the datagrid is selected
            SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
            SupplierCode_DataGrid.Focus();
        }

        private void btnInsertTestData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            GetData();

            //only insert test data if no rows exist
            if (_dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                string memo1 = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 Test Comments 1\par
}";

                string memo2 = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 Test Comments 2\par
}";

                InitializeHelper();

                result = _helper.InsertTblSupplier("1", "Acme 123", "51 my street", null, "12345", "Some City", "https://www.myUrl1.com", memo1);
                UpdateStatus(result);

                result = _helper.InsertTblSupplier("2", "Acme 456", "52 my street", null, "12345", "Some City", "https://www.myUrl2.com", memo2);
                UpdateStatus(result);

                GetData();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateStatus("Status: Data exists in table-test data not added.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Resources**:

- [rtf to textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253321/rtf-to-textblock)
- [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is caused by this line:

```
"supplier_Memo = '" + ContentSupplierMemo + "', " +
```

`ContentSupplierMemo` contains RTF that looks like `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252...`. When you concatenate this to your SQL statement, the backslashes are sent directly to MySQL, which interprets them as escape characters and corrupts your data.

The solution is to use parameterized SQL. I'm not familiar with your particular database wrapper (`dbConnection.UpdateMySqlDataRecord();`), but most libraries provide a way to add parameters to a command. In ADO.NET, it would be:

```cs
using var command = new MySqlCommand();
command.CommandText = @"UPDATE Supplier SET
    supplier_Code = @supplierCode,
    ...
    supplier_Memo = @supplierMemo
    WHERE supplier_Id = @supplierId;";
command.Connection = connection;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierCode", inpSupplierCode.Text);
...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierMemo", ContentSupplierMemo);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierId", valueSupplierId.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Finally, your use of `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());` is likely to corrupt data. You should avoid that and just save `ms.ToArray()` in a `LONGBLOB` column.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo project that shows how to store data from a TextBlock in a database. It also shows how to retrieve the data from the database and display it in a TextBlock.

The following code has been tested. `longblob` is used for `supplier_Memo`. Alternatively, one could use `mediumblob`, if it meets your needs.

It's also important to use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

---

Create a new `WPF App (.NET Framework)` project (name: DatabaseMySqlHN)

**VS 2019**:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DatabaseMySqlHN.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatabaseMySqlHN"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnCreateTbl" Click="btnCreateTbl_Click">Create Table</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnInsertTestData" Click="btnInsertTestData_Click">Insert Test Data</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="4" x:Name="btnGetData" Click="btnGetData_Click">Get Data</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="6" x:Name="btnSaveUpdate" Click="btnSaveUpdate_Click">Save/Update</Button>
        </Grid>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="SupplierCode_DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="SupplierCode_DataGrid_SelectionChanged"></DataGrid>

        <TabControl Grid.Row="4" x:Name="tabControl1">
            <TabItem Header="Memo">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock   Text="Comments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Margin="10,10" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkRed"/>
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="inpSupplierMemo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,70,10,0" Height="182" Width="Auto">
                        <FlowDocument Name="inpSupplierMemoFD">
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text=""/>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Name="textBoxStatus" IsReadOnly="True" Text="" Background="LightGray"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Database table**: Supplier

**Note**: In the code below, I've tried to maintain the database column names that were supplied in the OP. However, the table name really shouldn't be part of the column names.

Instead of naming the column `supplier_Code`, name the column `Code`.

Columns may need to be added/modified per your requirements.

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier (supplier_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                       supplier_Code varchar(4),
                       supplier_Name varchar(80),    
                       supplier_Address1 varchar(80),
                       supplier_Address2 varchar(80),
                       supplier_Zip varchar(80),
                       supplier_City varchar(80),
                       supplier_Url varchar(80),
                       supplier_MailSales varchar(80),
                       supplier_MailSupport varchar(80),
                       supplier_Memo longblob,
                       currency_Id int,
                       currency_Code varchar(4));
```

[image]

Create a class (name: HelperMySql.cs)

**HelperMySql.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DatabaseMySqlHN
{
    public class HelperMySQL
    {
        public string ConnectionStr { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public HelperMySQL(string serverName, string databaseName, string username, string userPwd)
        {
            ConnectionStr = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Uid={2};Pwd={3};", serverName, databaseName, username, userPwd);
        }

        public HelperMySQL(string serverName, int portNumber, string databaseName, string username, string userPwd)
        {
            ConnectionStr = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Database={2};Uid={3};Pwd={4};", serverName, portNumber, databaseName, username, userPwd);
        }

        public string CreateTableSupplier()
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                //for mySQL, use backticks if tablename has space in it
                //total max size for all columns is 65535 - excluding TEXT and BLOB
                string sqlText = @"CREATE TABLE Supplier (supplier_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                                           supplier_Code varchar(4),
                                                           supplier_Name varchar(80),    
                                                           supplier_Address1 varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Address2 varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Zip varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_City varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Url varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_MailSales varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_MailSupport varchar(80),
                                                           supplier_Memo longblob,
                                                           currency_Id int,
                                                           currency_Code varchar(4));";

                ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText);

                Debug.WriteLine("Info: Table created (Supplier)");
                msg = "Status: Table created (Supplier).";
                
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                msg = "Error: (CreateTableSupplier - MySqlException) - " + ex.Message;
                Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                //throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error: (CreateTableSupplier) - " + ex.Message;
                Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                //throw ex;
            }

            return msg;
        }

        public void ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlText)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
            {
                //open
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
                {
                    //execute
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        public int ExecuteNonQueryTblSupplier(string sqlText, string supplierCode, string supplierName, string supplierAddress1, string supplierAddress2, string supplierZip, string supplierCity, string supplierUrl, byte[] supplierMemo, int supplierId = 0)
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
            {
                //open
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
                {

                    //set values - if they exist
                    //if a value is null, one must use DBNull.Value
                    //if the value is DBNull.Value, and the table column doesn't allow nulls, this will cause an error

                    //add parameters setting string values to DBNull.Value
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = supplierId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierAddress1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierAddress2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierZip", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierCity", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierUrl", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierMemo", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = DBNull.Value;

                    //set values
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierCode))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierCode"].Value = supplierCode;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierName))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierName"].Value = supplierName;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierAddress1))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierAddress1"].Value = supplierAddress1;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierAddress2))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierAddress2"].Value = supplierAddress2;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierZip))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierZip"].Value = supplierZip;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierCity))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierCity"].Value = supplierCity;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierUrl))
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierUrl"].Value = supplierUrl;

                    if (supplierMemo != null && supplierMemo.Length > 0)
                        cmd.Parameters["@supplierMemo"].Value = supplierMemo;

                    //execute; returns the number of rows affected
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            return rowsAffected;
        }

        public DataTable GetDataTblSupplier(int supplierId = 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string sqlText = string.Empty;

            if (supplierId > 0)
            {
                sqlText = "SELECT * from Supplier where supplier_Id = @supplierId";
            }
            else
            {
                sqlText = "SELECT * from Supplier";
            }

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
            {
                //open
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
                {
                    //add parameter
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplierId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = supplierId;

                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        //use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }

        public string InsertTblSupplier(string supplierCode, string supplierName, string supplierAddress1, string supplierAddress2, string supplierZip, string supplierCity, string supplierUrl, byte[] supplierMemo)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Supplier  (supplier_Code, supplier_Name, supplier_Address1, supplier_Address2, supplier_Zip, supplier_City, supplier_Url, supplier_Memo) VALUES (@supplierCode, @supplierName, @supplierAddress1, @supplierAddress2, @supplierZip, @supplierCity, @supplierUrl, @supplierMemo);";

            try
            {
                int rowsAffected = ExecuteNonQueryTblSupplier(sqlText, supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplierZip, supplierCity, supplierUrl, supplierMemo);

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {

                    result = String.Format("Row added.");
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "Row not added.";
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier - MySqlException): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public string UpdateTblSupplier(int supplierId, string supplierCode, string supplierName, string supplierAddress1, string supplierAddress2, string supplierZip, string supplierCity, string supplierUrl, byte[] supplierMemo)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            string sqlText = "UPDATE Supplier SET supplier_Code = @supplierCode, supplier_name = @supplierName, supplier_Address1 = @supplierAddress1, supplier_Address2 = @supplierAddress2, supplier_Zip = @supplierZip, supplier_City = @supplierCity, supplier_Url = @supplierUrl, supplier_Memo = @supplierMemo WHERE supplier_Id = @supplierId;";

            try
            {
                int rowsAffected = ExecuteNonQueryTblSupplier(sqlText, supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplierZip, supplierCity, supplierUrl, supplierMemo, supplierId);

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    result = "Updated successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "No rows were updated.";
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier - MySqlException): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error (UpdateTblSupplier): " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace DatabaseMySqlHN
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private HelperMySQL _helper = null;
        private System.Data.DataTable _dt = null;
        private int _currentDataGridIndex = 0;
        private int _dbRowCount = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            InitializeHelper();

            //get data from database
            _dt = _helper.GetDataTblSupplier();

            //populate data in DataGrid from DataTable
            SupplierCode_DataGrid.DataContext = _dt;

            //set value
            _dbRowCount = _dt.Rows.Count;

            //clear existing data
            inpSupplierMemo.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        }

        private void GetMemo(int index)
        {
            byte[] dataArr = null;

            if (_dt != null && index >= 0 && index < _dt.Rows.Count)
            {
                //set value
                DataRow row = _dt.Rows[index];

                if (row["supplier_Memo"] != null && row["supplier_Memo"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    //get value from DataTable
                    dataArr = (byte[])row["supplier_Memo"];
                }

                if (dataArr != null)
                {
                    //Debug.WriteLine("Length: " + dataArr.Length);

                    //clear existing data
                    inpSupplierMemo.Document.Blocks.Clear();

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataArr))
                    {
                        //inpSupplierMemo.Document = new FlowDocument();

                        //load data
                        TextRange flowDocRange = new TextRange(inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentStart, inpSupplierMemo.Document.ContentEnd);
                        flowDocRange.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] GetRichTextFromFlowDocument(FlowDocument fDoc)
        {
            byte[] result = null;

            //convert to string
            if (fDoc != null)
            {
                TextRange tr = new TextRange(fDoc.ContentStart, fDoc.ContentEnd);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    result = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void InitializeHelper()
        {
            if (_helper == null)
            {
                //servername, databaseName, userName, userPassword
                _helper = new HelperMySQL("localhost", "HN", "testUser", "removed");
            }
        }

        private void InsertRow(int dgIndex)
        {
            //since the DataGrid DataContext is set to the DataTable, 
            //the DataTable is updated when data is modified in the DataGrid
            //get last row
            DataRow row = _dt.Rows[_dt.Rows.Count - 1];

            //get data from DataTable
            string supplierCode = row["supplier_Code"].ToString();
            string supplierName = row["supplier_Name"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress1 = row["supplier_Address1"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress2 = row["supplier_Address2"].ToString();
            string supplier_Zip = row["supplier_Zip"].ToString();
            string supplier_City = row["supplier_City"].ToString();
            string supplier_Url = row["supplier_Url"].ToString();

            //convert RTF to string
            byte[] memo = GetRichTextFromFlowDocument(inpSupplierMemo.Document);

            InitializeHelper();

            string result = string.Empty;
            result = _helper.InsertTblSupplier(supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplier_Zip, supplier_City, supplier_Url, memo);
            UpdateStatus(result);
        }

        private void UpdateRow(int dgIndex)
        {
            //when DataGrid SelectionChanged occurs, the value of '_currentDataGridIndex' is set
            //to DataGrid SelectedIndex
            //get data from DataTable
            DataRow row = _dt.Rows[_currentDataGridIndex];

            int supplierId = (int)row["supplier_Id"];
            string supplierCode = row["supplier_Code"].ToString();
            string supplierName = row["supplier_Name"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress1 = row["supplier_Address1"].ToString();
            string supplierAddress2 = row["supplier_Address2"].ToString();
            string supplier_Zip = row["supplier_Zip"].ToString();
            string supplier_City = row["supplier_City"].ToString();
            string supplier_Url = row["supplier_Url"].ToString();

            //convert RTF to string
            byte[] memo = GetRichTextFromFlowDocument(inpSupplierMemo.Document);

            InitializeHelper();

            string result = string.Empty;
            result = _helper.UpdateTblSupplier(supplierId, supplierCode, supplierName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2, supplier_Zip, supplier_City, supplier_Url, memo);
            UpdateStatus(result);
        }

        private void UpdateStatus(string msg)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
            {
                if (!msg.StartsWith("Error") && !msg.StartsWith("Status"))
                {

                    textBoxStatus.Text = String.Format("Status: {0} ({1})", msg, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Status: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), msg));
                }
                else
                {
                    textBoxStatus.Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", msg, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), msg));
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnCreateTbl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeHelper();

            //create table
            string result = _helper.CreateTableSupplier();
            UpdateStatus(result);
        }

        private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetData();

            //update status
            string msg = "Status: '" + _dt.Rows.Count + "' rows retrieved.";
            UpdateStatus(msg);
        }

        private void SupplierCode_DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;

            //set value
            _currentDataGridIndex = dg.SelectedIndex;

            GetMemo(dg.SelectedIndex);
        }


        private void btnSaveUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = _currentDataGridIndex;

            if (_dt.Rows.Count >  _dbRowCount)
            {
                InsertRow(SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateRow(SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            }

            GetData();

            // Make sure the eddited row in the datagrid is selected
            SupplierCode_DataGrid.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
            SupplierCode_DataGrid.Focus();
        }

        private void btnInsertTestData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            GetData();

            //only insert test data if no rows exist
            if (_dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                string memo1Str = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 Test Comments 1\par
}";
                //convert to byte[]
                byte[] memo1 = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(memo1Str);

                string memo2Str = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 Test Comments 2\par
}";
                //convert to byte[]
                byte[] memo2 = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(memo2Str);

                InitializeHelper();

                result = _helper.InsertTblSupplier("1", "Acme 123", "51 my street", null, "12345", "Some City", "https://www.myUrl1.com", memo1);
                UpdateStatus(result);

                result = _helper.InsertTblSupplier("2", "Acme 456", "52 my street", null, "12345", "Some City", "https://www.myUrl2.com", memo2);
                UpdateStatus(result);

                GetData();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateStatus("Status: Data exists in table-test data not added.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [rtf to textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253321/rtf-to-textblock)
- [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)