# If statement is not working well on giving Warning Messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am very very new to C# and I am in the process of doing my project for my studies using Winforms. The below code is not doing its work. When my richComResults (richTextBox) is empty, I want a messageBox to appear and says "There is nothing to be cleared!", but it doesn't say it, it shows the Yes/No dialog.

Please could you be kind enough to point out my mistakes? Your input would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
private void btnComClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richComResults == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to be cleared!");
        }
        if (richComResults != null)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear the results?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                richComResults.Clear();
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't want to check richComResults, you want to check richComResults.Text.

Comment: If you're using the RichTextBox that doesn't have the Text property, perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text

Comment: `null` is different than `String.Empty` or `""`. `null` means there is no value while `""` means that the strings value is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`richComResults` is your `RichTextBox` control, so it's probably not null... What you need to check is its `Text` property. It will probably not be null either, but it might be empty (keep in mind that an empty string is not the same as null). You can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to test both cases anyway:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(richComResults.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to be cleared!");
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check whether richtextbox is empty or not

```
if (richComResults.Text== "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("rich text box is empty");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("rich text box is not empty");
            }
```