# Error in using regex (verifying the code for regex)

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have this piece of code

```
string myText = new TextRange(mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.ContentStart,  
                      mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

//replace two or more consecutive spaces with a single space, and
//replace  two or more consecutive newlines with a single newline.
var str = Regex.Replace(myText, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                     mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new 
                      Run("Hello")))));
```

This is already working but the spacing still remains in between text sent.
how can I fix it or update my richtextbox? I am trying to eliminate the spacing in displaying a text to a richtextbox as shown

[image]

I want to show :

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

without the multiple newline or spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document is not of type string.

**EDIT**

```
string myText = new TextRange(richtextbox2.Document.ContentStart, richtextbox2.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

//replace two or more consecutive spaces with a single space, and
//replace  two or more consecutive newlines with a single newline.
var str = Regex.Replace(myText, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: so what object should I use? I know that .Text is not available in wpf c#

Comment: To get the Text in WPF see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text

Comment: yeah it is working but it did not remove the spacing in the richtextbox. hehe. How could I remove i?

Comment: You need to update the richtextbox with the new value.

Comment: you want to show like this "hellohellohello" or the space before hello?

Comment: mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Hello")))));

where should I put this? before or after?

Comment: I updated my code in the question. Please check if that is right. Thanks

Comment: You should put another question for this and what are you trying to do.

Comment: Hello is being displayed in every click and I have clicked 3 times. Not synchronously.

Comment: ah okay2. thanks by the way. I'll post another question