# Voice Enabled RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a WPF application that has a richtextbox which accepts dictations from the user as its input.

I want to use this code for the SpeechRecognized event for an an object of the SpeechRecognitionEngine class.

```
private void speechRecognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Result.Text = rtb.Text; //rtb is an object of the RichTextBox class
  }
```

The problem is that there is no Text property for the RichTextBox class. Is there any way of fixing this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox contents can be set via Document property. You can find more details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is an example from the link provided above. It creates a new document and a paragraph for it, then assigns the document to RichTextBox:

```
// Create a simple FlowDocument to serve as content.
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Simple FlowDocument")));
// Create an empty, default RichTextBox.
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
// This call sets the contents of the RichTextBox to the specified FlowDocument.
rtb.Document = flowDoc;
// This call gets a FlowDocument representing the contents of the RichTextBox.
FlowDocument rtbContents = rtb.Document;
```

Comment: Honestly, that doesn't help a lot. Can you specifically tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void speechRecognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
  {
       rtb.AppendText(e.Result.Text);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well documented problem and there are many different solutions for it. You can find a large number of possible solutions in the answers to the [RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property “Text”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text) question here on Stack Overflow.

However, my preferred method would be to declare a `Text` Attached Property for the `RichTextBox` class. Please see the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to find out more about Attached Properties. You can find out what code to use in your `Text` Attached Property for the `RichTextBox` class in the [RichTextBox Text property where are you hiding?](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/richtextbox-text-property-where-are-you-hiding/) tutorial on C# Disciples website.