# Get text from dynamicly created RichTextBox in onChange event

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How can I get the text from a dynamicly created `RichTextBox` and a dynamicly created `rtb_TextChanged` Event?

e.g:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Name = "rtb" + i;
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        rtb.TextChanged += rtb_TextChanged;

        Controls.Add(rtb);

    }

    void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string s = rtb.Text;    //How can I get the rtb.Text?
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text

Comment: Or of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: Omg, thank you, i've searched but didnt found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `sender` argument of your event handler:

```
void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)sender;
    string s = rtb.Text;
    //... etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the event parameter : `sender`

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
       RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)sender;
       var str = rtb .Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First rtb is not the name that you called the textbox.  Since the textbox sent the message you could cast the sender to a textbox and look at its text property.