# Controlling the Length of a RichTextBox in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I need to do something like this [Controlling the Length of a RichTextBox in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34056/Controlling-the-Length-of-a-RichTextBox-in-C)

but in WPF :

```
if (richTextBox.Text.Length > maxsize)
            {
                // this method preserves the text colouring
                // find the first end-of-line past the endmarker

                Int32 endmarker = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf('\n', dropsize) + 1;
                if (endmarker < dropsize)
                    endmarker = dropsize;

                richTextBox.Select(0, endmarker);
                richTextBox.Cut();
            }
```

This throws compilation errors

> Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2  No overload for method 'Select' takes 2 arguments

Apparently the Text property does not work in WPF, see this page [RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property “Text”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text) with this question I found solution for the property Text but no for Select method.

```
 var myText = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

            if (myText.Text.Length > maxsize)
            {
                // this method preserves the text colouring
                // find the first end-of-line past the endmarker

                Int32 endmarker = myText.Text.IndexOf('\n', dropsize) + 1;
                if (endmarker < dropsize)
                    endmarker = dropsize;

                richTextBox.Select(0, endmarker);//No overload for method 'Select' takes 2 arguments
                myText.Select(0, endmarker);//No overload for method 'Select' takes 2 arguments
                console.Cut();
            }
```

So now, How do I achieve this in WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not used WPF before, but is it the `Document` property? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) describes it as "Gets or sets the FlowDocument that represents the contents of the RichTextBox."

Comment: @Ric I updated my question and see that solve the problem of property Text but not for Select method.

Answer (score 3):

RichTextBox does not have Text property, what you are doing right now is the way to go, you can improve your code by moving it to an global extension method:

```
  public static class Extentions
    {
        public static string Text(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
        {
            TextRange content = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            return content.Text;           
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
If your final goal is to select some text from the control, you wont need Text property at all:

For RichTextBox Selection you have to user TextPointer:

```
TextPointer text = richTextBox.Document.ContentStart;
while (text.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) != TextPointerContext.Text)
{
    text = text.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
}
TextPointer startPos = text.GetPositionAtOffset(0);
TextPointer endPos = text.GetPositionAtOffset(endmarker);
var textRange = new TextRange(startPos, endPos);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
```

EDIT 2: To append text to RichTextEditors.

```
private void processLine(string line)
{
    //You can clear if necessary
    //richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();

    //whatever your logic. I'm only taking the first 10 chars
    string trimmed = text.Substring(0,9); 
    richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(trimmed)));
}
```

Comment: I updated my question this is the solution for the property Text but no for Select method.

Comment: Really I need trim text when it reaches a certain size.So  GetPositionAtOffset and TextPointer  is good idea for solve the problem of select some text. I don't understand the code of the while loop. To simplify and clarify I need a method that receives a text line and append this line at Text in RichTextbox and in case that the amount of data become too large, trim text when it reaches a certain size.

Comment: So you are receiving texts from another source and, after verification, you want to append it to the RichTextBox?

Comment: Yes, This is What I want

Comment: Ok, you can check now

Comment: I vote up because your answer help me , but not solve all my problem, I need remove the first lines

Comment: Sure, that is what richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear() is for.

Comment: For Select method use yourRichTextBox.Selection.Text