# Convert Spellbox to a RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, winforms, richtextbox, spell-checking

Hans Passant has code that adds a textbox based spellbox for spell checking in WinForms app.  It works great but I would like to know if it could be converted to a RichTextBox so that I could add bolding, color, etc.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
//[DesignerSerializer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
class SpellBox : ElementHost
{
    public SpellBox()
    {
     //   string templatePath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\AviationMaintenanceLogger\\Templates\\";
        box = new TextBox();
        base.Child = box;
        box.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        Uri lex_file = new Uri(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\AviationMaintenanceLogger\\Templates\\AML.lex");
        box.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(lex_file);
        box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        box.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        this.WordWrap = true;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);

    }
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return box.Text; }
        set { box.Text = value; }
    }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Multiline
    {
        get { return box.AcceptsReturn; }
        set { box.AcceptsReturn = value; }
    }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool WordWrap
    {
        get { return box.TextWrapping != TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
        set { box.TextWrapping = value ? TextWrapping.Wrap : TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new System.Windows.UIElement Child
    {
        get { return base.Child; }
        set { /* Do nothing to solve a problem with the serializer !! */ }
    }

    private TextBox box;
}
```

This is the new code that works:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Drawing;

[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
//[DesignerSerializer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
class SpellBoxNew : ElementHost
{
    public SpellBoxNew()
    {
        //   string templatePath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\AviationMaintenanceLogger\\Templates\\";
        box = new RichTextBox();
        base.Child = box;
        box.IsReadOnly = false;
        box.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        Uri lex_file = new Uri(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\AviationMaintenanceLogger\\Templates\\AML.lex");
        box.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(lex_file);
        box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        box.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        //this.Font = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
        // this.WordWrap = true;
        this.Multiline = true;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
           // string richText = new TextRange(transcriberArea.Document.ContentStart, transcriberArea.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
            string richText = new TextRange(box.Document.ContentStart, box.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
            return richText;
        }
        set
        {
            box.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            box.Document.Blocks.Add(new System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph(new Run(value)));
        }
    }


    public bool Multiline
    {
        get { return box.AcceptsReturn; }
        set { box.AcceptsReturn = value; }
    }
    [DefaultValue(false)]

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new System.Windows.UIElement Child
    {
        get { return base.Child; }
        set { /* Do nothing to solve a problem with the serializer !! */ }
    }


    private RichTextBox box;
```

Comment: Maybe you should link the code so your audience knows what you are talking about.

Comment: Seems fairly straight forward.  Start by changing TextBox to RichTextBox and go from there.

Comment: I did that, I changed:

Comment: box = new RichTextBox();

        private RichTextBox box;

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return box.Text; }
        set { box.Text = value; }
    }
The Get/Set box.Text throws an error.

Comment: Don't keep the error to yourself if you want help.  What does it say?

Comment: Sorry, here is the error ---> "RichTextBox does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of 'RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?)"

Comment: Clearly you are going to have to post your code for us to help fix that.  Despite what you wrote, it looks like your box variable is not a RichTextBox control.  Did you try to create your own RichTextBox class?

Comment: Where you see TextBox in this code, I changed it to RichTextBox but it fails on the public override string Text Get and Set.  The project now crashes the project so I can't post any of the code.  If you paste the code above into a project and make the change you should get the same results.

Comment: See [RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property “Text”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/957441/719186)

Comment: Lars Tech, that worked!  Thank you so much for your help and patience.  I am new to C# and Stackoverflow.